# Setup SSH server by hostname?

Tags: networking, ssh, dns

I am a newbie in networking and I am trying to setup a SSH server, so that I can access the files on my host. I used openssh-server to successfully setup and connect to the server (on LAN).

While connecting, I use my IP address: e.g. ssh username@10.139.55.14 etc.

Now the problem is, my host gets the IP address dynamically, so every time I restart my host machine, the SSH server will have a different location (IP address).

I tried using avahi-daemon and could not connect using my hostname.

I have 2 questions:

If my host is on the same network, how can I access it using the hostname (I don't want to enter the IP address while connecting)?

If my host machine is on my home network, how can I access it from my Work network?

I remember, on Windows, if my host and client are on the same network, I can simply connect using the hostname.

.

The basic idea is I could have my host machine at

(a) Work (LAN) where I cannot access the router.

(b) at home (Using the internet) .

I want to access the host machine, without using the IP address. And I want to access all the files on my host machine. Is there any easy solution to this?

Comment: When you say "my host gets the IP address dynamically, so every time I restart my host machine" Are you just talking about your linux machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need to do is take advantage of a service like [Dyn DNS](http://alternativeto.net/software/dyndns/).

This will cause your server to periodically update the DNS records to point to your servers dynamic IP address.

Comment: When DynDns was being difficult about keeping accounts active,  basically shutting down a hostname if the right hoops were not jumped through, my backup method was to have the home machine send an email periodically to a free email account hosted at gmail.  If my home IP had changed, and DynDns had stopped working, I could always go to the gmail account and look at the email.  I put the IP address in the email body,  but I could have just looked at the original headers too.  I have not checked, but I suspect DynDns is even more difficult these days than then.

Comment: well, now, DynDNS is paid, and my router (Netgear 3000 NAS100) does not support any other DDNS provider (like No-IP)
I need to change the router or buy the DynDNS subscription. Is there any other (free) way?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed when you said my host, you mean your linux box

1. Set a static IP on your Linux box so you have a static IP
2. on your Router Enable DDNS, DynDNS is no longer free, i personally use http://www.noip.com. this would give you a public hostname like yourname.noip.com

**If you router doesn't support no-ip then you can flash it with DD-WRT, DD-WRT supports no-ip.com**

3. Change SSH port from default 22 to something in the five digit like 55555. using default is very insecure
4. Forward your port SSH port to your Unix Box. I take it that would be the new static local IP you have from Step 1

Comment: well, now, DynDNS is paid, and my router (Netgear 3000 NAS100) does not support any other DDNS provider (like No-IP)
I need to change the router or buy the DynDNS subscription. Is there any other (free) way?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Flash Netgear 3000 with DD-WRT, this is the one i use it support noip and many others